# How can change fields name with list of labels when I am registring my model in django admin site

Tags: django, admin

I registered my model in admin.py, I want to change some model fields name with list of labels. I know how to do it in forms but mentioning labels in Admin model class are not reflecting it on Admin site. I need help how to use list of labels in Admin.py

```
class eAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', 'phone_number', 'email_id', 'country', 'state')
    list_filter = ('funnel', 'country', 'state')
    search_fields = ['email_id']
    exclude = ('city',)
    class Meta:
        labels = labels_list

admin.site.register(EApplications, eAdmin)
```

I have more than 20 fields I can't do it manually in models.py
I want to use labels list

Answer (score 2):

You need to create forms in `forms.py` here i give you hit

`forms.py` file create in your app

```
from .models import EApplications
from django import forms

FIELDS_NAME=['name', 'phone_number', 'email_id', 'country', 'state',"etc your field name"]
FIELDS_LABEL=["Enter Name","Enter phone_number","Enter email","Enter country","Enter state","etc your field label"]

label_list=dict(zip(FIELDS_NAME,FIELDS_LABEL)) #dictionary of fields label pare

class EApplicationsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=EApplications
        fields='__all__'
        labels=label_list #assign label
```

`admin.py` file in your app need following update

```
from .forms import EApplicationsForm # import the form in this file
class eAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', 'phone_number', 'email_id', 'country', 'state')
    list_filter = ('funnel', 'country', 'state')
    search_fields = ['email_id']
    exclude = ('city',)
    form=EApplicationsForm #here assign imported form EApplicationsForm

admin.site.register(EApplications, eAdmin)
```

> If you looking more dynamic rather than static, you need to define function which get data from model and  **zip it with relative fields with labels**. And make same thing ahead at all. 
>   Just do it at your project and let me know your result...!!

Answer (score 1):

in your models you can add verbose field names

```
first_name = models.CharField("person's first name", max_length=30)
```

or you can utilize help_text

```
help_text="Please use the following format: <em>YYYY-MM-DD</em>."
```

see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/models/#verbose-field-names, https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#help-text

Comment: I have more than 20 fields I can't do it manually, is there any better way?

Comment: i have updated the answer you can use any of those mentioned or you have to give the same name as field name to be displayed in your fields